# python 2.7.6 f2py and ipython --pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, f2py

I found a strange behaviour while using f2py compiled fortran modules to read floating point numbers from ascii files within ipython. Test file 'test.txt' contains only one float:

```
5.945
```

The subroutine I use to read the file can be something like:

```
subroutine read_test
implicit none
real :: dum
open(10,file='test.txt')
read(10,*) dum
print*, dum
close(10)
return
end subroutine read_test
```

Compiled with

```
f2py -c test.f90 -m test
```

If I simply use python or ipython without commandline options the numbers are read like they are in the file.

```
In [1]: import test
In [2]: test.read_test()
  5.94500017
```

Using ipython --pylab or --matplotlib gives

```
In [1]: import test
In [2]: test.read_test()
  5.00000000
```

This happens with python 2.7.6, ipython 2.3.0, numpy 1.8.2, and matplotlib 1.4.3. I tried as well ipython 3.0.0, 4.0.0, and 4.0.1, numpy 1.9.2 and 1.10.2, and matplotlib 1.4.3 or 1.5.10. Only switching to python 2.7.10 seems to change the expected behaviour.

Can someone explain to me what's going wrong. Unfortunately, 2.7.6 is the default in our whole environment and upgrading would be a bit of a trouble.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated python code?

Comment: No, but what exactly do you mean? there's only the shared library test.so generated by f2py.

Comment: I have a vauge memory of seeing an issue like this go by on a mailing list and that it was related to `locale` settings.  Does this also happen with python3?

Answer (score 0):

Enough random googling hit these [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4885) and [ipython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6158) bug reports.

TL;DR, check what `locale.getlocale()` returns.  The problem is likely that you have a locale that uses something other than `.` for separating the decimal and doing `export LC_ALL=C` will fix your problem.

I also assume you are on a mac?

Comment: Actually you are right. That is the problem. After starting ipython with --pylab i get ('de_DE', 'UTF-8') for 2.7.6 and (None, None) for 2.7.10. Exporting LC_ALL=C fixes the problem...btw I'm sitting on a ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: huh, ok.  One of the comments in those issues made me think it was a mac  specific issue.